# Is relying on query parameters to trigger events a a security risk in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger some events based on parameters on the url, does doing that pose a security risk. 
Example
Url= examples.com?#job
Then I do 
Spl=Url.split('?') 
$('a'+spl[1]) .trigger('click').

The example is working, I just want to know if this does not pose a security risk

Answer (score 2):

As long as the user can able to see without login, it is fine and you cannot really stop users to tweak Javascript.

If something can be done through javascript, no matter what you can't stop users to do it :)

If that is a secure page, check authentication on server side using filters or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what's on the page. Imagine if you had ads, for example - if I were an unscrupulous advertiser, I could send out a load of spam with links to `examples.com?#myEvilAd`and get users to automatically click on it.

This might sound like I'm being paranoid - and you're probably right :p But generally that's the right attitude to have when it comes to web security.

I think a better way to handle this would be to have a whitelist of sorts - rather than feeding the URL suffix straight into the event, do something like this:

```
var spl = url.split("?");

if (spl.length > 1) {
    switch (spl[1]) {
        case "#job":
            $("a #job").trigger("click");
            break;

        case "#job2":
            $("a #job2").trigger("click");
            break;
    }
}
```

Now you can be sure only things you've explicitly allowed will be processed.